# More efficient way to classify

Tags: python, pandas

```
normal = []
nine_plus []
tw_plus = []

for i in df['SubjectID'].unique():
    x= df.loc[df['SubjectID']==i]
    if(len(x['Year Term ID'].unique())<=8):
        normal.append(i)
    elif(len(x['Year Term ID'].unique())>=9 and len(x['Year Term ID'].unique())<13):
        nine_plus.append(i)
    elif(len(x['Year Term ID'].unique())>=13):
        tw_plus.append(i)
```

Hello, I am dealing with a dataset that has 10 million rows. The dataset is about student records and I am trying to classify the students into three groups according to how many semesters they have attended. I feel like I am using very crude method right now, and there could be more efficient way of categorizing. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could calculate `len(x['Year Term ID'].unique())` once per loop, instead of 1-4 times.

Comment: Please provide some more context for this. We can't even test potential solutions right now.

Answer (score 1):

You go through a lot of repeated iterations that are likely to make your data frame *slower* than a simple Python list.  Use the data frame organization in your favor.

- Group your rows by `Subject_ID`, then `Year_Term_ID`.
- Extract the count of rows in each sub-group -- which you currently have as `len(x(...`
- Make a function, lambda, or extra column that represents the classification; call that `len` expression `load`:

  0 if load <= 8 else 1 if load <= 12 else 3

Use that expression to re-group your students into the three desired classifications.

Do *not* iterate through the rows of the data frame: this is a "code smell" that you're missing a vectorized capability.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: Yeah I was looking for answers like yours :) thanks!